# Remove agent from timeMeasureStart if it already exist in it

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have an agent that pass through `timeMeasureStart` then it may or may not pass through `timeMeasureEnd`.

But agent is in loop so once agent pass through `timeMeasureStart` it can again pass through `timeMeasureStart` with out passing `timeMeasureEnd`. So I have to remove the agent from `timeMeasureStart` before it enter again in `timeMeasureStart` **otherwise it will through an error**:

*The agent has already been through this object; must go through TimeMeasureEnd first*

**My Solution:**

we can remove an agent from `timeMeasureStart` using

```
timeMeasureStart.remove(ped);
```

Bu the problem is I want to check first that the agent already exist in the `timeMeasureStart` or not. If it exist then i can remove it otherwise it will through an error.

i am trying to achieve something like that

```
if(agent exist in timeMeasureStart){
timeMeasureStart.remove(agent);}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a much easier solution would be to provide a `selectOutput` before that `timeMeasureStart` object. Also, add a **boolean** variable to the agent and name it `start` with an initial value `false`.

On the On Enter of the timeMeasureStart block add the code:

```
agent.start = true;
```

And your selectOutput condition would be:

```
agent.start
```

Comment: you are right but my original logic is much complex so if I can trace and remove the agent from "timeMeasureStart" then it will be much easy for me.

Comment: Same concept applies. Create a variable that becomes true when the agent enters the timeMeasureStart object. So in your last code of your question the if condition will be that variable. Why wouldn't that work?